# The Pick and Place Autonomous Demo, tabletop detection failed with error NO_TABLE, trying again

Tags: ros, pr2-tabletop-manipulation-apps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After the following steps I got the above error, robot can move its arm but can not  detect table and object. I use the remote database,ubuntu 11.04 64 bit electric ros.

1. export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
   export ROBOT=sim
2. roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
3. rosrun gazebo spawn_model -urdf -file table.urdf -model table -x 1.0 -y 0.5 -z 0.3
   4.rosrun gazebo spawn_model -gazebo -file `rospack find gazebo_worlds`/objects/coffee_cup.model -model coffee_cup -x 1.2 -z 1
4. roslaunch pr2_tabletop_manipulation_launch pr2_tabletop_manipulation.launch
5. rosrun pr2_pick_and_place_demos pick_and_place_demo.py
6. input start or d enter
   det to detach the object in the gripper
   q to quit
   press enter to continue
   d
   [INFO] [WallTime: 1329522623.706395] [811.514000] detecting objects
   [INFO] [WallTime: 1329522623.706753] [811.514000] calling tabletop detection
   [ERROR] [WallTime: 1329522624.229342] [811.621000] tabletop detection failed with error NO_TABLE, trying again
   [ERROR] [WallTime: 1329522624.584169] [811.659000] tabletop detection failed with error NO_TABLE, trying again
   [ERROR] [WallTime: 1329522624.986114] [811.751000] tabletop detection failed with error NO_TABLE, trying again
   [ERROR] [WallTime: 1329522624.986445] [811.751000] tabletop detection failed too many times.  Returning.
   type:

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27849/the-pick-and-place-autonomous-demo,-tabletop-detection-failed-with-error-no_table,-trying-again/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answer by myself:
since the remote server is not available. I do not know the reason. I try to run the local server for the database, now the demo works.

---

Originally posted by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) with karma: 287 on 2012-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-08**:
Also true in my case, i use the pipeline recently and it seems they donot support remote server anymore

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-11-08**:
Also true in my case, i use the pipeline recently and it seems theydonot